# Debugging Heroku Compile Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm not sure what to do if I have a compile error after I deploy to heroku.  Things are working okay on my system locally.

This is what I am getting from the Heroku console:

```
Z-Kidds-MacBook-Air:sample_app zkidd$ heroku console
Ruby console for warm-rain-75.heroku.com
```

> > User.create(:name => "Example User", :email => "user@example.com",
> >         SyntaxError: compile error
> >         /home/heroku_rack/lib/console.rb:150: syntax error, unexpected $end
> >          User.create(:name => "Example User", :email => "user@example.com",
> >                                                                            ^
> >             /home/heroku_rack/lib/console.rb:150
> >             /home/heroku_rack/lib/console.rb:150:in `call'
> >             /home/heroku_rack/lib/console.rb:28:in`call'
> >             /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'

Blindly, I ran heroku db:migrate, thinking that might help, but it did not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This won't work on your local machine too. You have an extra/are missing an `end` in your controller hence the `unexpected $end` message.

Comment: Sam. . . I'm not sure that's the case.  The page is working fine locally.  It's when I log into heroku and try to create a user that I get the ":Syntax Error: compile error" message

Comment: can you create a user on your local machine?